# Can the Admin UI be used without the user authenticating in Django 1.3?

Tags: django, django-admin

I was wondering if there's an easy way to configure the Django Admin UI (eg at http://mysite.com/admin) so that I don't need to authenticate/login?

I've tried tweaking urls.py but couldn't get it to bypass the login screen:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

I'd like to go to http://mysite.com/admin and see the list of django objects without having to login.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

- Django admin framework uses '`is_staff`' flag on the '`User`' object to verify the permission to use admin site.
- So it needs an user to be authenticated to verify his admin related permissions.
- If you want to disable this, you have to override the 'index' method of the admin site.
- It is available at `django.contrib.admin.sites`.

`def index(self, request, extra_context=None):`

```
     """
     Displays the main admin index page, which lists all of the installed
     apps that have been registered in this site.
     """
```