# Django Admin without Authentication

Tags: python, django

Is there a ready way to use the Django admin page without any form of authentication? I know I can use [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15755292/can-the-admin-ui-be-used-without-the-user-authenticating-in-django-1-3), but that was for Django 1.3. Are there any changes that would let me do this more easily in Django 1.6?

My main motivation for this is that I want to have as few database tables as possible, and I am using this only locally, so there is no need for any sort of authentication (I'm only ever running the server on localhost anyways).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Create a module `auto_auth.py`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin

class AutoAuthMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    def process_request(self, request):
        request.user = User.objects.filter()[0]
```

Edit `MIDDLEWARE` in your `settings.py`:

- Remove `'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware'`
- Add `'auto_auth.AutoAuthMiddleware'`

You can change `User.objects.filter()[0]` to something else if you want a particular user.

---

In response to your comment: yes.  To run the Django admin without users at all, try this:

```
class User:
    is_superuser = True
    is_active = True
    is_staff = True
    id = 1

def return_true(*args, **kwargs):
    return True
User.has_module_perms = return_true
User.has_perm = return_true

class AutoAuthMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    def process_request(self, request):
        request.user = User()
```

And remove `'django.contrib.auth'` from `INSTALLED_APPS`

But if you use any apps that depend on the auth app, you're going to have a bad time.

Comment: Is there a way to do away with users completely or is the admin site tied specifically to the User model? Or, could I create a new fake superuser for each request?

Comment: thank you! I am using this as a simple editor for an SQLite database for a completely separate application, so this will work perfectly.

Comment: Note that in Django 1.10, the [interface to middleware changed](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/middleware/#upgrading-middleware).

Comment: This Answer is outdated.

Comment: Does not work with Django 3.2

Answer (score 18):

The accepted answer is already super simple however after messing around with this I found that in recent versions of Django (since admin.site.has_permission became a thing... >= 1.8?) you can do it without middleware.

In your project's urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin

class AccessUser:
    has_module_perms = has_perm = __getattr__ = lambda s,*a,**kw: True

admin.site.has_permission = lambda r: setattr(r, 'user', AccessUser()) or True

# Register the admin views or call admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
    # Your url configs then...
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

If you have AccessUser extend User you can leave out the `__getattr__` portion which is a hacky way to return something when user.pk or similar is called.

Comment: Note that when one tries to change something using this construction, django admin complains: `insert or update on table "django_admin_log" violates foreign key constraint "django_admin_log_user_id_c564eba6_fk_auth_user_id"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(1) is not present in table "auth_user".`, so you do need to have a user if you need that functionality.

Comment: This is what i was looking for past one week. I didn't need login page since my application is internally used.

Comment: Here a ticket with solution for problem mentioned by @Jieter: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58736821/prevent-django-admin-changes-from-creating-a-logentry

Answer (score 5):

### The accepted answer adapted for Django version >= 1.10

`/[yourapp]/middleware.py`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class AuthenticationMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        request.user = User.objects.filter()[0]
        return self.get_response(request)
```

In `[yourproject]/settings.py` for the `MIDDLEWARE` list:

- Comment or remove: `'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',`
- Append: `'[yourapp].middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',`

Probably obvious to most people but note that the solution still requires one user to exist. Create one manually `python manage.py createsuperuser` or automatically with a script:

- [How to automate createsuperuser on django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6244382/how-to-automate-createsuperuser-on-django)
- [Autocreate superuser with each schema django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38019532/autocreate-superuser-with-each-schema-django)
- [Create django super user in a docker container without inputting password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30027203/create-django-super-user-in-a-docker-container-without-inputting-password)

Answer (score 4):

**Another Option allows access from anyone:** get the first user to bypass authentication

```
# app/admin.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
anonymous_user = User.objects.all().first()
admin.site.has_permission = lambda r: setattr(r, 'user', anonymous_user) or True
```

Answer (score 0):

For the newer versions of django >=2.1 you need to do something like this:

**auto_auth.py**

```
class User:
    is_superuser = True
    is_active = True
    is_staff = True
    id = 1
    pk = 1


User.has_module_perms = True
User.has_perm = True


class Middleware(object):
     def __init__(self, get_response):
          self.response = get_response

     def __call__(self, request):
         request.user = User()
         return self.response(request)
```

And also don't forget to modify your settings middleware and deactivate `django.contrib.auth` and add `auto_auth`

Comment: `(admin.E408) 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware' must be in MIDDLEWARE in order to use the admin application.`

Comment: @simon which django version you're using ?

Comment: 3.0 -- must be a new thing, I suppose.

Comment: Ah! i'll check this code against v3 and i'll update my post. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score -1):

For all using Django 3.0,

comment out this code ***AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'customUser'*** in your settings.py and create a superuser (*python manage.py createsuperuser*) with the default user model first.

After creating the superuser then uncomment this code ***AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'customUser'***.

This happened to me and that's what I did with Django 3.0

You should be good to go. Hope it helps

Comment: not recommended at all, this will lead to two user model at one time. this can lead to great inconsistencies as you scale up. I HIGHLY SUGGEST you refactor your code to remove that!!