# Django 2.1 created migration with makemigrations did not show up in migrations folder

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

The migration process runs within a docker environment.

After running `docker-compose run web python manage.py makemigrations` terminal showed

> Migrations for 'api_app':
>   api_app/migrations/0004_analysis_error.py

But the file didn't show up in the local directory. I ran `docker-compose run web python manage.py migrate` and it even showed:

> Applying api_app.0004_analysis_error... OK

But still no api_app.0004_analysis_error.py in the local directory.

I also tried making an empty migration, the same behavior occurred.
I also tried removing the changes and resetting the migrations, no changes were detected (even though there were).

The application name has been included in the [INSTALLED_APP] module in settings.py.

Comment: Are you sure the file did not show up there? Maybe if you are using and IDE, it takes some time for it to refresh. Can you confirm that the file is not there even if you open the directory in your OS' file explorer?

Comment: @OzgurAkcali yes, even in file explorer it didn't show up, also tried `ls` in the terminal for the migrations folder, same thing. I confirm it has init.py

Answer (score 0):

The issue is similar to this:
[Why am I unable to run django migrations via the 'docker-compose run web' command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41435014/why-am-i-unable-to-run-django-migrations-via-the-docker-compose-run-web-comman)

When running `docker-compose run` it created the migration file in the new container but not copied to local.

To grab the file out of the container:
[Copying files from Docker container to host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22049212/copying-files-from-docker-container-to-host)