# Can't log into a commandline created superuser using Django but account gets created

Tags: python-3.x, django, docker-compose, account, superuser

I have created a superuser that i can't log into, using the docker-compose.yml commands:

```
sh -c "sleep 5 &&
#<snip>
 echo A-fj... create superuser acct... &&
 echo DJANGO_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD=$DJANGO_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD &&
 echo DJANGO_SUPERUSER_EMAIL=$DJANGO_SUPERUSER_EMAIL &&
 echo DJANGO_SUPERUSER_USERNAME=$DJANGO_SUPERUSER_USERNAME && 
 python manage.py createsuperuser --noinput --username $DJANGO_SUPERUSER_USERNAME  --email $DJANGO_SUPERUSER_EMAIL &&
 echo Z-fj... create superuser acct... done. &&
#<snip>
sleep 5 "
```

The environment variables display perfectly, and an account gets created that i can see in the db using dBeaver.

When i manually add a second user via "$python manage.py createsuperuser" dialog, i end up with an account that i can log into.

When i copy the password from User2 to User1, i can then log into User1 using User2 password, so it seems to be a password thing.

When i compare the passwords from User1(orig) and User2(new), they look to be different formats...

I'm not sure, but thinking it may be a clue to the problem...
Password1 is shorter and has no sections where Password2 is longer...

Password1:

!GSU8f8hmNOl1oJBfe1Epk7ocJiXXWQQp3G0mh9TC

Password2:
pbkdf2_sha256$120000$IAkHkB3ME9aB$p0hrZPkLeSWK0IafqVQ1dEtR5kgBol7WnU7QELoo6KE=

I've tried a few different passwords, just in case, but no go

[image: Screenshot comparing 2 passwords in dBeaver]

Comment: printenv DJANGO_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD results in empty?

Answer (score 0):

You should set `DJANGO_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD` environment variable in non interactive mode otherwise the password would not be set (Django password would be set to unusable string in this case)

as [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/django-admin/#createsuperuser) states

> In non-interactive mode, the USERNAME_FIELD and required fields
> (listed in REQUIRED_FIELDS) fall back to
> DJANGO_SUPERUSER_<uppercase_field_name> environment variables, unless
> they are overridden by a command line argument. For example, to
> provide an email field, you can use DJANGO_SUPERUSER_EMAIL environment
> variable.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding... but I stated that the environment variables are set (implied because I'm seeing them in the 3 echo's... (that I set in the .env file))... and that they are displayed JUST before the line "python manage.py createsuperuser --noinput..." in the script above.  I took these variables from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30027203/ post "Sep 24 at 15:52" where user2579823 lists the 3 env variables needed, and that "Note there is no need to put the password, as Django's createsuperuser script takes that from DJANGO_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD by default in noninteractive mode"

Answer (score 0):

Are you attempting to set the env vars with the lines that look like

```
...
echo DJANGO_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD=$DJANGO_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD
...
```

Because I think that is just echoing that string which is why the superuser is being created without a password.

If you're not sure if the vars are being set before you invoke `createsuperuser`, dump your env vars right before that command.

Try removing the echo.

Comment: of course not LoL  The echo is just for feedback.

Answer (score 0):

No, the echo is just echoing.
Just there for troubleshooting