# Django deployment with docker - create superuser

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, django-admin

I have 3 environments set up and cannot createsuperuser. The way I migrate and runserver now follows the container so I have an entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
  1
  2 echo "${RTE} Runtime Environment - Running entrypoint."
  3
  4 if [ "$RTE" = "dev" ]; then
  5
  6     python manage.py makemigrations --merge
  7     python manage.py migrate --noinput
  8     python manage.py runserver 0:8000
  9
 10     python manage.py createsuperuser --username "admin" --email "admin@banl.com" --password "superuser"
 11     echo "created superuser"
 12
 13 elif [ "$RTE" = "test" ]; then
 14
 15     echo "This is tets."
 16     python manage.py makemigrations
 17     python manage.py migrate
 18     python manage.py runserver
 19
 20 elif [ "$RTE" = "prod" ]; then
 21
 22     python manage.py check --deploy
 23     python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
 24     gunicorn kea_bank.asgi:application -b 0.0.0.0:8080 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker
 25
 26 fi
```

lines 10/11 is what I want to make work, I think I have a syntax issue. Originally I wanted the password and username to be variables stored in an env file:

```
1   RTE=dev
  1 POSTGRES_USER=pguser
  2 POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pgpassword
  3 POSTGRES_DB=devdb
  4 DJANGO_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD=superuser
  5 DJANGO_SUPERUSER_EMAIL=admin@bank.com
  6 DJANGO_SUPERUSER_USERNAME=admin
```

But now I just want it to work, I need to create a superuser account in order to develop.
Can anyone spot what's wrong?
I can see my application on localhost:8000, but how do I create the superuser in this scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to `createsuperuser -h` and this [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/django-admin/#createsuperuser), `createsuperuser` command does not support `--password` flag. to read arguments from environment variables, you should use this command with `--noinput` flag and set required fields like username, email and password as `DJANGO_SUPERUSER_<uppercase_field_name>` in your env file.

`python manage.py createsuperuser --noinput`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! it worked
Fixed with entrypoint.sh line: `python manage.py createsuperuser --noinput --username $DJANGO_SUPERUSER_USERNAME --email $DJANGO_SUPERUSER_EMAIL`

Answer (score 1):

***Automate / Create django superuser during docker - compose up.***

Create a python file.Like

> createsuperuser.py

Keep this file with django project. sometimes docker-compose can not find this because of wrong place of this file. so be careful.

```
from django.db import IntegrityError
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

import environ # This package import from 'django-environ' https://pypi.org/project/django-environ/
env = environ.Env(
    DEBUG=(bool, False)
)

try:
    superuser = User.objects.create_superuser(
        username=env('SUPER_USER_NAME', default="abcd"),
        email=env('SUPER_USER_EMAIL', default="abc@gmail.com"),
        password=env('SUPER_USER_PASSWORD', default="abc"))
    superuser.save()
except IntegrityError:
    print(f"Super User with username {env('SUPER_USER_NAME')} is already exit!")
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Now in docker-compose.yml under the django project image in command section add. I'm adding details docker-compose file so that you can get help for others section

> python manage.py shell < createsuperuser.py

```
backend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/backend/Dockerfile
    image: backend:pos-backend
    container_name: pos_backend
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/home/pos
      - static:/home/pos/staticfiles
      - media:/home/pos/mediafiles
    environment:
      DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: pos.settings
    command: >
      /bin/bash -c "python manage.py makemigrations  --noinput
      && python manage.py migrate  --noinput
      && python manage.py shell < createsuperuser.py
      && python manage.py collectstatic  --noinput
      && gunicorn pos.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000"
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    expose:
      - 8000
    env_file:
      - ./backend/.env.dev
    depends_on:
      - db
    restart: on-failure
```