# django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2005, "Unknown server host 'db' (11001)")

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

Im trying to create a superuser for my django app using `python manage.py createsuperuser` but i keep getting an error message. Im using docker for my app alongside a pipenv and a connection is established whenever i run `docker compose up -d --build` for both the app and the db. `settings.py` is also properly configured and uses the `db` service as the HOST. However this is the error im getting when im running `python manage.py createsuperuser` after running the previous command:

```
PS C:\Users\nawar\Desktop\uni\Uni\Modules\UWE_Modules\Y3\DESD\CW2\mlaas-g7> python manage.py createsuperuser
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nawar\.virtualenvs\mlaas-g7-hyj7l3ZN\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 282, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\nawar\.virtualenvs\mlaas-g7-hyj7l3ZN\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\nawar\.virtualenvs\mlaas-g7-hyj7l3ZN\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 263, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\nawar\.virtualenvs\mlaas-g7-hyj7l3ZN\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\nawar\.virtualenvs\mlaas-g7-hyj7l3ZN\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 247, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\nawar\.virtualenvs\mlaas-g7-hyj7l3ZN\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 123, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\nawar\.virtualenvs\mlaas-g7-hyj7l3ZN\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 185, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (2005, "Unknown server host 'db' (11001)")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nawar\Desktop\uni\Uni\Modules\UWE_Modules\Y3\DESD\CW2\mlaas-g7\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\nawar\Desktop\uni\Uni\Modules\UWE_Modules\Y3\DESD\CW2\mlaas-g7\manage.py", line 18, in main 
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\nawar\.virtualenvs\mlaas-g7-hyj7l3ZN\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\nawar\.virtualenvs\mlaas-g7-hyj7l3ZN\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\nawar\.virtualenvs\mlaas-g7-hyj7l3ZN\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 402, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\nawar\.virtualenvs\mlaas-g7-hyj7l3ZN\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\management\commands\createsuperuser.py", line 88, in execute
    return super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\nawar\.virtualenvs\mlaas-g7-hyj7l3ZN\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 447, in execute
    self.check_migrations()
  File "C:\Users\nawar\.virtualenvs\mlaas-g7-hyj7l3ZN\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 564, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
  File "C:\Users\nawar\.virtualenvs\mlaas-g7-hyj7l3ZN\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "C:\Users\nawar\.virtualenvs\mlaas-g7-hyj7l3ZN\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 58, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "C:\Users\nawar\.virtualenvs\mlaas-g7-hyj7l3ZN\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 235, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "C:\Users\nawar\.virtualenvs\mlaas-g7-hyj7l3ZN\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 81, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "C:\Users\nawar\.virtualenvs\mlaas-g7-hyj7l3ZN\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 57, in has_table
    with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
  File "C:\Users\nawar\.virtualenvs\mlaas-g7-hyj7l3ZN\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\nawar\.virtualenvs\mlaas-g7-hyj7l3ZN\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 323, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "C:\Users\nawar\.virtualenvs\mlaas-g7-hyj7l3ZN\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 299, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "C:\Users\nawar\.virtualenvs\mlaas-g7-hyj7l3ZN\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\nawar\.virtualenvs\mlaas-g7-hyj7l3ZN\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 281, in ensure_connection
    with self.wrap_database_errors:
  File "C:\Users\nawar\.virtualenvs\mlaas-g7-hyj7l3ZN\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\nawar\.virtualenvs\mlaas-g7-hyj7l3ZN\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 282, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\nawar\.virtualenvs\mlaas-g7-hyj7l3ZN\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\nawar\.virtualenvs\mlaas-g7-hyj7l3ZN\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 263, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\nawar\.virtualenvs\mlaas-g7-hyj7l3ZN\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\nawar\.virtualenvs\mlaas-g7-hyj7l3ZN\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 247, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\nawar\.virtualenvs\mlaas-g7-hyj7l3ZN\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 123, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\nawar\.virtualenvs\mlaas-g7-hyj7l3ZN\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 185, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2005, "Unknown server host 'db' (11001)")
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
  mlaas:
    image: mlaas
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    depends_on:
      - db
    entrypoint: ["./mlaas-entrypoint.sh"]

  db:
    image: mysql:8.0-debian
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mysql-root
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: prediction_db
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql

volumes:
  db_data:
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.10-slim

WORKDIR /app

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential default-libmysqlclient-dev

COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8000
```

I can open the web app and i can see a valid connection for the database but i keep getting this error for various `manage.py` commands.

I have a wait-for script for the database as well for my entrypoint shell script for the database:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Waiting for MySQL Database Service to start..."

./wait-for db:3306

python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate

python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Comment: Where are you running the `python manage.py createsuperuser` command? Inside the container or in a terminal / command prompt on your PC / laptop?

Comment: Im running the command in my vscode terminal locally.

Comment: Duplicate of: [Create django super user in a docker container without inputting password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30027203/create-django-super-user-in-a-docker-container-without-inputting-password)

Comment: its not just that as i said, i try to type `python manage.py shell` and in the shell i try to add a record for my table and i get the same error, even though the database connection is established (meaning i can see a ping and can access the database from DataGrip in my case).