# Prevent django admin changes from creating a LogEntry

Tags: django, django-middleware

I want to use the Django admin so I include `django.contrib.admin` in my middleware, but by default this adds a `django_log_entry` table and triggers the creation of a log entry on all additions, changes, and deletions. How do I prevent this behavior? Should I overwrite the `LogEntry` model or can I simply unregister it? I can't seem to find any documentation.

I'm using Django 2.1

Answer (score 3):

I've created a [Django Python package](https://pypi.org/project/django-admin-logs/) that allows you to disable admin log entries. To use it:

1. Install from PyPI:

   `pip install django-admin-logs`
2. Include it in your INSTALLED_APPS settings:

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = (
        ...
        'django_admin_logs',
        ...
    )
```

3. Also add the following to your settings file:

   `DJANGO_ADMIN_LOGS_ENABLED = False`

This will stop Django from creating admin log entries.